# Looking for animated movie with a scene where a young man makes flowers grow from his father's hair

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was a movie I saw as a young child, which means it was probably made in the 80's or earlier, though conceivably it could have been early 90's.  It was animated, but I don't recall if it was Japanese or Western.

The scene I remember most clearly is a young man coming to a house where an older man and woman live; I believe it was a son coming home to his parents.  However, he now serves some sort of monstrous big-bad and has magical powers.  I remember he made flowers grow out of his father's hair and one grow out of his nose.  His mother brushes away the flowers from the hair but not the one on the nose.

Later, the big bad has some evil scheme going on that turns humans into these nondescript block people that look like they are crude stone carvings of people.  They all start marching together, and you can tell that one of them is the boy's father because it still has a flower coming out of its nose.

I also remember a scene where the block people are climbing on each others' shoulders to make a big tower, and I think the main badguy is inside.  The badguy himself is some sort of ghost or monster - I don't remember specifically, but I'm pretty sure he was non-human.

There *might* have been a unicorn as a major character in this story, but I may be confusing it with a different movie.

Does anyone know what show I'm talking about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Unico in the Island of Magic](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086515/).

The main character, Unico, is a unicorn.

Here's some excerpts from [a plot summary](http://packsjunk.blogspot.com/2013/08/unico-in-island-of-magic-part-1.html):

> The stranger winds up agreeing to let the cat serve him, as he needs
>   someone to help him find other forest animals to turn into "living
>   puppets."  Unfortunately, the stranger can't seem to hit a moving
>   target when it's the size of a rabbit or smaller, and when Melvin
>   tries to point him towards Unico, Unico manages to get away and makes
>   the two guys chasing him crash their tree into another tree.
>
> Oh, and apparently the stranger is serving a "master" somewhere, which
>   means we now have three layers of evilness going on.

And

> He shows off a few magic tricks to his family, including making a
>   small log turn into a doll, swinging a door shut, and making flowers
>   sprout out of his father's head and face.

The link includes images of the flower magic, as well as the transformed parents.

[image]

Comment: This is it!  Thanks, I've been off-and-on wondering what this was for years!